# Removing Back slashes from Swift 5 String

Tags: swift, string

I am trying to remove `\` from a string in Swift 5, unfortunately I cannot get it working, I've tried both of these approaches and neither worked:

`let urlString = videoSource.filter {$0 != "\""}`

`let urlString = videoSource.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "", options: NSString.CompareOptions.literal, range: nil)`

How can I remove them?

Comment: Are you sure your string contains backslashes? Try printing them to make sure. IMO your strings are correct. Btw your code would remove quotes not backslashes.

Comment: ```.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\", with: "")``` ?

Comment: I am sure, I am printing out before/after the action. both are the same

Comment: @RajaKishan why not simply `.filter { $0 != #"\"# }`

Comment: If the backslashes are inside a string literal they are most likely virtual to escape double quotes (like in your `filter` example).

Comment: @aFella print or log ? make sure to `print` its value.

Comment: @LeoDabus Hot take, but using .replacingOccurrences is more readable IMO.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by more readable than a simple filter method. Note that you are not “replacing” you are removing characters

Comment: Note that OP is removing collection elements (Character) not subsequences (Substring). Using that method in this case IMO is totally pointless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\` is used for escaping characters. So for Swift this string literal `"\""` actually means just `"`. You should use `"\\"` first slash needed for escape another one